# Upgrading wso2is from lower version of wso2

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are planning to upgrade our WSO2 Identity server (WSO2 IS 4.6.0) to version wso2is 5.4.0. Is there a process/upgrade path to upgrade from a lower version of WSO2 IS? Also, do we need to do anything different for migrating our User store to the new WSO2 IS. We are using SQL Server as our WSO2 database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are migrating WSO2 IS from 4.6.0 to 5.4.0, you will require first to migrate your WSO2 IS 4.6.0 to WSO2 IS 5.0.0 first.
Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release for migration steps.

Then you can upgrade it from 5.0.0 to 5.4.0 by changing the currentVersion and migrateVersion properties in migration-config.yaml. (Refer [https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release) for more information on the steps).

Comment: Hi, I am trying to upgrade our wso2 using the links provided. Under Upgrading the database section, Step 3 says "Once you run the migration script on the production database, copy your configurations to the staging database you created. This becomes the new database for your new version of IS." My question is after running the migration script on my existing production database, what does copy your configurations to staging database you created means?. The staging database was an empty database created. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Hi Mandar, it seems the documentation is bit ambiguous in this point. If you have any database related configurations that you used in the previous production database, you need to add them to the staging database. Other than that you need to restore the data dumped from the previous production database to the staging database.

Comment: Hi Chamalee, Thanks for updating on this. So when we ran the migration script on the Production database, we assumed that all the latest DB definition was updated on the Production database. So, next we will have to restore the database from the Prod to the Staging and use the staging with the new version of wso2. Is my understanding correct? If yes, why can't we use the same prod database which has been upgraded with the wso2 version scripts?

Comment: Hi Mandar, yes you can do that as a second step. If you have an idea of what is staging environment and what is production environment you can get this. We use staging to test the setup whether the operations are working properly with the migrated data. Please refer Going into production section in the same documentation.